Clarification on asio::co_composed
This seems in the vein of the "Side-tangent" of Can asio co_composed lambda function capture this pointer?, but my smooth brain still doesn't have a good handle on C++20 coroutines in the land of asio.  The original goal was to be able to adaptor C++20 coroutine work into proper completion tokens.
Given the contrived example below and at godbolt:
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
// Mock ASIO thing
struct tcp {
    template <asio::completion_token_for<void(boost::system::error_code)> Token>
    auto send(Token&& token) {
        auto tim = std::make_unique<asio::steady_timer>(exe_, 1ms);
        return tim->async_wait(
            asio::consign(std::forward<Token>(token), std::move(tim)));
    }
    asio::any_io_executor exe_;
};

// Encapsulated async work
struct my_work {
    std::shared_ptr<tcp> ss;
    int count_ = 0;
    asio::awaitable<void> step1() {
        std::cout << "step1" << std::endl;
        co_await ss->send(asio::deferred);
    }
    asio::awaitable<void> step2() {
        std::cout << "step2" << std::endl;
        co_await ss->send(asio::deferred);
    }
    asio::awaitable<void> do_work() {
        co_await step1();
        // Mock ASIO call
        auto t = std::make_unique<asio::steady_timer>(ss->exe_, 1ms);
        co_await t->async_wait(asio::deferred);
        // Some fake logic
        if (count_++ < 2) {
          co_await step2();
        } else {
            // This would actually come from deeper in asio
             throw boost::system::system_error{asio::error::connection_aborted};
        }
        std::cout << "ran " << count_ << std::endl;
    }
};
#define CO_SPAWN 1
// Adaptor for other completion tokens
template <typename CompletionToken>
auto my_work_adaptor(asio::any_io_executor exe, std::shared_ptr<my_work> wrk,
               CompletionToken&& token) {
    return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code)>(
        asio::co_composed(
            [](auto state, asio::any_io_executor& exec,
               std::shared_ptr<my_work> wrk) -> void {
                state.reset_cancellation_state(boost::asio::enable_terminal_cancellation());
                boost::system::error_code ec{};
                try { 
                    while(!state.cancelled()) {
                        auto t = std::make_unique<asio::steady_timer>(exec, 1s);
                        co_await t->async_wait(asio::deferred);
#if CO_SPAWN
                        co_await asio::co_spawn(exec, wrk->do_work(),asio::deferred);
#else
                        co_await wrk->do_work();
#endif
                    }
                } catch (const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
                    ec = ex.code();
                }
                std::cout << "echo" << std::endl;
                co_yield state.complete(ec);
            },
            exe),
        token, std::ref(exe), wrk);
}
int main() {
    asio::io_context io{};
    auto t = std::make_shared<tcp>(io.get_executor());
    auto bb = std::make_shared<my_work>(t);
    my_work_adaptor(io.get_executor(), bb, [](auto ec) { std::cout << "work done " << ec.what() << std::endl; });
    io.run();
}

I am trying to understand exactly why CO_SPAWN=0 fails.  The return value of the do_work() is an asio::awaitable so wouldn't co_await act the same on it?  Likewise, then why does the async_wait compile just fine?
Is it because the do_work() is not really a coroutine until it is run by the co_spawn call?  Is it because the completion token asio::deferred causes the async_wait to become a coroutine?
Most important of all: Am I making this more complicated than it should be? I just wanted the do_work() to work with completion tokens.
